# How do I make an image change to another one?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how do I make the image change to another one, then change back to normal, because the following code doesn't work:

```
function change(){
    img = document.getElementById("img")
    img.src = "Login_img2.jpg"
    img.onclick = "change2()"
}

function change2(){
    img = document.getElementById("img")
    img.src = "login_img3.jpg"
    img.onclick = "changeN()"
}

function changeN(){
    img = document.getElementById("img")
    img.src = "login_img1.jpg"
    img.onclick = "change()"
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to check the answer as accepted for whichever solution worked for you best.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I think downvotes were beacause of OP attitude, not for the content of the question itself (btw, I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 4):

You're `onclick` functions are being invoked immediately since you're including `()` after the function (also, dont quote them!). Try changing to something like this:

```
function change(){
    img = document.getElementById("img")
    img.src = "Login_img2.jpg"
    img.onclick = change2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A completely different approach: Just hold all image-sources in an array and a variable to show, which image is currently shown. Then you just have to cycle through this array, without having to change the clickhandler every time.

```
(function(){
  // list of images
  var images = [ "login_img1.jpg", "login_img2.jpg", "login_img3.jpg" ],
  // current shown image
      curImage = 0;

  // event handler
  document.getElementById( 'img' ).addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    // get next image in line
    curImage = (curImage + 1) % images.length;
    // assign it
    this.src = images[curImage];
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7pKxb/ which might give you some ideas.

I'd prefer using flag then swapping between them on click

```
 if (blFlag) {
    blFlag = false;
    oTux.setAttribute('src', 'http://tux.crystalxp.net/png/brightknight-tux-hatches-3796.png');
 } else {
    blFlag = true;
    oTux.setAttribute('src', 'http://mascot.crystalxp.net/png/pit-tux-sonic-4206.png');
}
```